# How to test state changes with component methods

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a component and need to test the methods it has to update state. These methods update the state and I'm having some trouble with testing those state changes.

My test is as follows:

```
  it('componentDidMount() test', () => {
    const loancont = shallow(<LoanFilesContainer store={store} searchText='testing' firstUpdate={false} uploadingExcel={true}/>)
    const prewrap = mount(loancont.get(0))
    const loancontwrap = prewrap.find('LoanFilesContainer')
    const wrapper = mount(loancontwrap.get(0))
    expect(wrapper.state('firstUpdate')).toEqual(false)
    wrapper.instance().state.uploadingExcel = true
    wrapper.instance().componentWillUpdate()
    wrapper.update()
    expect(wrapper.state('firstUpdate')).toEqual(true)
  })
```

My code is as follows:

```
class LoanFilesContainer extends Component {
    state = {
      searchText: '',
      isBulkCreating: false,
      loansToConvert: [],
      uploadingExcel: false,
      firstUpdate: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fees.filter({ limit: 0 })
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
      const { uploadingExcel, firstUpdate } = this.state
      if(uploadingExcel && !firstUpdate) { this.setState({ firstUpdate: true }) }
      if(uploadingExcel && firstUpdate) { this.setState({ uploadingExcel: false, firstUpdate: false }) }
    }

    render() {
      const { ...props } = this.props
      const {
        searchText,
        isBulkCreating,
        loansToConvert,
        uploadingExcel
      } = this.state

      return (
        <main className="main">
          {props.loans.data && (
            <LoanFiles
              data-test="input"
              {...props}
              handleCSV={this.handleCSV}
              searchText={searchText}
              onFieldChange={this.onFieldChange}
              onSearchSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}
              onOrderAll={this.onOrderAll}
              uploadRef={this.uploadRef}
            />
          )}
          {(props.loans.isLoading || !props.loans.data || props.orderAdd.isLoading || props.upload1003.isLoading) && <Loader/>}
          {isBulkCreating ? <BulkLoader title='Creating Orders In Bulk...' /> : null}
          {uploadingExcel && <BulkLoader title='Uploading Loan Data...' />}
          {!isBulkCreating && loansToConvert.length > 0 ? <ChainedCreateOrderModal loans={
            loansToConvert
          } onFinish={this.onChainedOrderCreationFinish} /> : null}
        </main>
      )
    }
}
```

The firstUpdate state should change to true based on the if statement checking the state of uploadingExcel and firstUpdate. However it returns false still even after updating.

Comment: There's more than 150 lines of code in your question. I think you need a Freelancer to do the job. I suggest to show only the area where you think the error is

Comment: @josemartindev I have updated the question with the code that is being used only.